# Vercel serverless function not running axios post request

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am using Vercel serverless function to run a post request to webhook.
This works correctly on localhost but not working after deploying to Vercel serverless function.

```
async function formSubmission(req, res) {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  console.log('form-submission-init');
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://flow.zoho.in/*',
    data: req.body,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('fail', error);
    });
  res.json({ data: 'done' });
}
```

Vercel logs `form-submission-init`
Vercel logs do not print either `fail` or `success`

I have gone through Vercel's documentation on why it may not work [link](https://vercel.com/support/articles/why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed) but unsure.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have async flow problem, you are sending response `res.json` before `axios` promise is actually resolved.

You either need to await axios request, or put `res.json` inside promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem recently, but I finally solved it. This is my code, and I hope it can help you.

```js
const axios = require('axios')

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    const json = req.body;

    let output = parseData(json);

    let data = {
        msg: output
    };

    // webhook
    if (output.startsWith("The price is")) {
        let price = output.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
        // Use await to wait for the webhook request to finish
        try {
            await sendWebhook(price);
            console.log("Webhook request sent successfully!");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error sending webhook request:", error);
        }
    }

    // Send the response after the webhook request is resolved
    res.status(200).json(data);
};

function sendWebhook(price) {
    let msg_url = `http://api.xxxxx.app/Va5GhE/${price}`;
    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: msg_url,
        headers: {}
    };

    // Return the axios promise so that it can be awaited in the calling function
    return axios.request(config);
}
```